# Dynamically passing and using data to a WPF application without restarting it

Tags: c#, wpf, events

It's my first post on StackOverflow, so please be patient with me :)

I'm looking out for a way to pass a value to an already running application. The application should be able to accept this value and use it for further operations during its lifetime. I'd prefer not to logoff/restart the application in order to use the updated value.

The scenario would be something like this:

The application uses MachineName to initialize and populate some objects while it is being instantiated. Once it is up and running, I would like to pass a different workstation name to the application (possibly from command line) and the application should be able to use this MachineName and use it further down the line. I dont mind if I have perform same operations again to initialize the required objects with new MachineName name.

The application in question is a WPF app with C#. It's also using some WCF services as well. I was thinking to use a common registry key to store the workstation name and this registry key needs to be used/updated in the application. So it should be the first point of contact. But I'm not sure if this is a better approach. Any ideas please?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  So, what's wrong with just having an input field in the application somewhere to accept a new machine name? Otherwise, it sounds like you are trying to make something that is simple incredibly complex.

Comment: If it is a WPF application then why do you want to read from the command line?  WPF has UI.  Why not just have text box for workstation name and a button for process?

Comment: @Blam: As mentioned below, I cant use the direct input from the user in my app. I need to get the new machine name without disturbing the current application flow..

Comment: How is "(possibly from command line)" not direct user input?   Your WPF app cannot have a flow and an active UI?

Comment: @Blam - Thanks for your input.. that's how the app is designed... it is basically a hosting platform of sorts in which other applications can host themselves.. so this app does not have a "UI" of it's own.. So i have to find a way to pass it in background only.. However, I've figured out an existing functionality in my app which can be used to trigger the workstation change... So I'm trying it out..

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to watch a file on disk using a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).  When your app gets a change notification, re-read the contents of the file and update your app state.

Answer (score 0):

The application listen to a socket port or watch a shared file when it starts up, if the application is called again with parameter, just open the socket port or write the command to the file, the first application can do the re-initialization .

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you might be over-complicating things a bit. If all you need to do is give your application a new string "MachineName", then you have several options (this is certainly not all of your options, just a few to think about):

1. Since this is a WPF application, we can assume some user is interacting with it...otherwise it may as well just be a console app. If this is the case, create a view giving the user the ability to change the MachineName. Perhaps a ComboBox listing all available MachineNames and a button to begin the re-initialization you need.
2. You apparently already have the plumbing in place for service calls. You could have your application act as both a client AND a service, allowing you to remotely (read: outside of this application) update your MachineName.
3. You can set this application up to monitor a specific directory or file (as pointed out by @jlew) and when some change occurs to that file, your application will read the change (the new MachineName) and begin it's re-initialization routine.

I don't know your full set of requirements, but I would probably set it up for both 1 and 2, which will give you a little more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your comments. The design of my application is such that it's trying to find out the machine name using code. And there are also checks to determine whether the app is running on a local desktop, virtual machine or any virtualization software such as Citrix/VMWare etc. So I can't put the combobox in the app.. The third option suggested looks useful and I'll try it out...